# java: how to implement math parsing

Tags: java, parsing, math, matrix

I am trying to implement a simple math parser in java. This is for my small school project working with matrices that enables to input some simple equations, such as A^-1(B+C) and then the program asks to input matrices A,B and C and outputs result for these operations.

What I got so far is a class called MathParser, that creates objects of class Operation. 
Operation has methods like `setOperation` ( one of plus,times,inverse,power) and `addInput`(Matrix|Operation|int) and finally `executeOperation()` that loops all items from addInput() and executes chosen operation from setOperation. If it finds that some item from the input is instance of class Operation, it executes it first - this is a sort of recurrent calling. It is done this way to manage operation order - multiplying comes before addition etc.

However, I don't find this solution very good. Do you have any ideas how to implement such a task?

Comment: There are so many way this has been done, I suggest you look at some of these http://www.google.com/search?q=java+math+parser 103,000 hits

Comment: What do you want it to support? Probably simple operations such as `+`, `-`, `/`, etc., and matrices I guess? Any more? Can you make use of a tool that generates these classes for you, or do you have to "hand-code" the parser?

Comment: I'd rather write it on my own, so I can learn something new :) I was also thinking that it would be a great feature if it can calculate equations, such as Ax+B = C => x = A^-1*(C-B) and do some other stuff from linear algebra, but I'll leave that for later.

Comment: No, you don't solve Ax = b with A^{-1}b. You first perform {LU|Cholesky|QR} decomposition of A and solve for x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canonical method for parsing mathematical expressions is the shunting yard algorithm. It is a very simple and elegant algorithm, and implementing it will teach you a lot.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm has a good description, complete with a worked example.

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe this solution is not exactly what you need/want to implement or maybe it's a overkill, but I'd go with some scripting engine (for example Groovy). In that case this is how your code would look:

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell();
shell.setVariable("a",10);
shell.setVariable("b",20);
int result = ((Number) shell.evaluate("(a+b)/2")).intValue();
```

Moreover, you can also parse formulas of any complexity or even using your specific calculation functions. You just put it all into the shell and then evaluate the input string.

**Added:**
Operators do not work with matrices by default, but it is not hard to implement that with groovy as it supports operator overloading (read more about it here: http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operator+Overloading)

So here is an example with matrices:

```
class Matrix {
    private int[][] data;

    public Matrix(int[][] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int[][] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    //Method that overloads the groovy '+' operator
    public Matrix plus(Matrix b) {
        Matrix result = calculateMatrixSumSomehow(this,b);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now in your call will look like this:

```
shell.setVariable("A",new Matrix(...));
shell.setVariable("B",new Matrix(...));
Matrix result = (Matrix)shell.evaluate("A+B"); //+ operator will use 'plus' function
```

Comment: Added an example on how to use that with matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using embedded scripting?

Answer (score 0):

i released an expression evaluator based on [Dijkstra's Shunting Yard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm, under the terms of the [Apache License 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html):

http://projects.congrace.de/exp4j/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://bracer.sourceforge.net It's my implementation of shunting-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using library built specifically for math expression parsing, such as [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/). You will get a lot of very helpful options:

**1 - Checking expression syntax**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("2+3-");
e.checkSyntax();
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getErrorMessage());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] [2+3-] checking ...
[2+3-] lexical error 

Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 4.
Was expecting one of:
    "(" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    <UNIT> ...
    "~" ...
    "@~" ...
    <NUMBER_CONSTANT> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <FUNCTION> ...
    "[" ...

[2+3-] errors were found.
```

[mXparser-v.4.0.0]

**2 - Evaluating expression**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("2+3-(10+2)");
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] 2+3-(10+2) = -7.0
```

**3 - Using built-in functions constants, operators, etc..**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Expression e = new Expression("sin(pi)+e");
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] sin(pi)+e = 2.718281828459045
```

**4 - Defining your own functions, arguments and constants**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Argument z = new Argument("z = 10");
Constant a = new Constant("b = 2");
Function p = new Function("p(a,h) = a*h/2");
Expression e = new Expression("p(10, 2)-z*b/2", p, z, a);
mXparser.consolePrintln(e.getExpressionString() + " = " + e.calculate());
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] p(10, 2)-z*b/2 = 0.0
```

**5 - Tokenizing expression string and playing with expression tokens**

```
import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;
...
...
Argument x = new Argument("x");
Argument y = new Argument("y");
Expression e = new Expression("2*sin(x)+(3/cos(y)-e^(sin(x)+y))+10", x, y);
mXparser.consolePrintTokens( e.getCopyOfInitialTokens() );
```

Result:

```
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  --------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] | Expression tokens: |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |    TokenIdx |       Token |        KeyW |     TokenId | TokenTypeId |  TokenLevel |  TokenValue |   LooksLike |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           0 |           2 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |         2.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           1 |           * |           * |           3 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           2 |         sin |         sin |           1 |           4 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           3 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           4 |           x |           x |           0 |         101 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           5 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           6 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           7 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           8 |           3 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           1 |         3.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |           9 |           / |           / |           4 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          10 |         cos |         cos |           2 |           4 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          11 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          12 |           y |           y |           1 |         101 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          13 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          14 |           - |           - |           2 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          15 |           e |           e |           2 |           9 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          16 |           ^ |           ^ |           5 |           1 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          17 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          18 |         sin |         sin |           1 |           4 |           3 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          19 |           ( |           ( |           1 |          20 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          20 |           x |           x |           0 |         101 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          21 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           4 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          22 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          23 |           y |           y |           1 |         101 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          24 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           2 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          25 |           ) |           ) |           2 |          20 |           1 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          26 |           + |           + |           1 |           1 |           0 |         NaN |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0] |          27 |          10 |       _num_ |           1 |           0 |           0 |        10.0 |             |
[mXparser-v.4.0.0]  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**6 - Whats equally important - you will find much more in** [mXparser tutorial](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/), [mXparser math collection](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-math-collection/) and [mXparser API definition](http://mathparser.org/api/).

**7 - mXparser supports:**

- JAVA
- .NET/MONO
- .NET Core
- .NET Standard
- .NET PCL
- Xamarin.Android
- Xamarin.iOS

Best regards